# Journey Builder entering second journey after finishing first

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm fairly new to Marketing Cloud and wonder if it's possible for subscribers to enter a second journey one or two days after the first one was completed? Can I achieve that through the Automation Studio? How to trigger such action?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. Have an Updatecontact activity at the end of journey one to insert a value into a DE that you then use as a flag for beginning Journey 2.
2. Create a SQL Query in Automation Studio to run every day or so to find those that have this flag and the date of exit was 1-2 days ago then push them to an entry DE for Journey

There are other ways, including via a custom built Journey Log, API tracking events, etc. But I find the above to be the easiest to implement and execute.

Sample SQL:

```sql
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM [myDE]
WHERE exitFlag = 1
AND CAST(exitDate as Date) = CAST(GetDate() - 2 as Date)
```